# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - RT3290 Wi-Fi driver problem, already tried every solution

Tags: wireless, 18.04, asus

So, I'm on Ubuntu for ~10 years, last 8 years using LTS. So I have run on all different sorts of issues and particularly on this one, about 3 times (on every distribution upgrade...). But now I searched all over forums, blogs, IRC channels (even translated Russian), tried to compile new driver, all sorts of wizards and terminal input, but no help.
Is anyone managed to fix it?

```
gaucho@asus:~$ uname -a
Linux asus 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
gaucho@asus:~$ cat /home/gaucho/wireless-info.txt

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Nov 2018 19:32 CET +0100

Booted last: 13 Nov 2018 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:570c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 25a7:fa23  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    24576  4 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  45056  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.1.138/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 42597sec preferred_lft 42597sec
    inet6 fe80::/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.138 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1102     1  0 02:38 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Auto Ethernet
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       1ea299a5-95d5-4142-9c64-3dd2759979ba
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.138/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        host_name = asus
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1542176532
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.138
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 21600
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 37800
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{70}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   1ea299a5-95d5-4142-9c64-3dd2759979ba | Auto Ethernet

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Frane-Bol Tours]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Frane-Bol Tours | type=wifi | permissions=user:gaucho:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Frane-Bol Tours
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

nl80211 not found.

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rt2800pci

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2x00pci 
blacklist mac80211
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist cfg80211
blacklist wl
blacklist lib80211_crypt_tkip
blacklist lib80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf]
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2x00pci  

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rt2800pci.conf]
blacklist rt2800pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/etc-modules-parameters.conf]
options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/ralink-bt.conf]
install rtbth /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rtbth; mknod /dev/rtbth c 192 0; /usr/bin/rtbt &

##### rc.local ##########################

modprobe brcm80211
exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x1814:0x3290 (rt2800pci)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8187)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan2"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8187)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan3"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 3874.103726] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 3875.724653] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 3877.210373] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 3877.289236] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 3877.289306] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 3877.290924] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 3878.849467] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 3878.849481] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

P.S. on the other side, Bluetooth isn't functional from day buying laptop and installing Ubuntu on it :D

Comment: " so I have run on all different sort of issues ..." What issues? Why is the default driver for your device blacklisted?

Comment: "already tried every solution" implies that no solution will fit.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by removing some of the blacklist entries, do

`gedit admin:///etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and remove the following entries

```
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2x00pci 
blacklist mac80211
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist cfg80211
blacklist wl
blacklist lib80211_crypt_tkip
blacklist lib80211
```

Save and exit gedit, then

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rt2800pci.conf
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
sudo sed -i 's/modprobe brcm80211/#modprobe brcm80211/' /etc/rc.local
sudo sed -i 's/rt2800pci/#rt2800pci/' /etc/modules
```

Reboot and if it isn't working do `./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Post URL as a comment